# Relaxing 6 questions in a 24-hour period constraint?

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, rate-limiting

I see

> You can only ask 6 questions in a 24-hour period.

This is somewhat restrictive for binge coders.

Can this be somehow modified to take into account the reception of the 6 previously asked questions  (e.g. if they're positively received, then perhaps more could be allowed)

Comment: It doesn't restrict binge *coding*, it restricts binge *asking*.

Comment: Even if you had more than 6 good questions on a particular day, it seems very unlikely that you'd continue to have 6 or more every day of the week. This seems like a rare problem that would solve itself anyway after a day or so.

Comment: Assuming you're sleeping 8 hours a day and subtracting a bit for eating and stuff, asking 6 questions in 24 hours would mean asking a question about every 2 hours. This seems like very little time spent researching before asking a question. Being able to ask more in that period would be bad, imho.

Comment: @user5783745 If you have to ask more than 6 questions a day on a new technology where there are no answers yet it seems like you outsource all of your original research... Seems not ideal. And I don't want to read questions posted after 24 hours of no sleep either, they would probably be not good (and it's not healthy).

Comment: Seems to me that the throttle works exactly as designed: it prevents a flood of spontaneous questions with little research. You have yet to provide compelling evidence why that’s a bad thing.

Comment: Anyway, I repeat that some *compelling* reasoning why one should be able to ask more than 6 questions a day would go a long way towards supporting your goal here. At the moment it’s just “because I’d like to”, and we’re not very impressed by your track record, so that’s not really helping.

Comment: Let’s say that experience has shown that more than 6 questions a day rarely result in high quality questions. Even if you happen to be the exception, there are many more for whom this throttle works exactly as designed. Again, if you want to support your own pledge here, [edit] it to add some reasoning, preferably backed by facts and numbers.

Comment: I am not sure if I could write two good questions a day, let alone six... every time I encountered a user asking several questions a day all those questions were pretty bad ones. I think 3 questions per day would be better limit.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar hmm In a productive day I can easily write 20-30 questions, and all of them are good because I need these to make progress in some coding job (it just somehow happens that when I enter these in web search they appear to be already asked and answered, typically at Stack Overflow)

Comment: @gnat I should have said good questions for which I cannot find the answer ;)

Comment: [Optimizing For Pearls, Not Sand](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/)

Comment: I agree that this constraint is bad - reduce it to 2.

Comment: Users who abuse SO for paid work, compete homework assignments and/or as free labour to answer other's assignments for a fee are one reason why I no longer answer questions.  I've had enough of getting used by selfish deadbeats:(   It's unfortunate that the tiny number of new accounts that do not regard other SO users as slave drones get to suffer but, well, tough.  It's my time to not waste.

Comment: The massive number of downvotes means "nope, not happening."

Answer (score 30):

No, 6 well researched and well written questions a day is a very hard goal to achieve already.

There are also plenty of downsides including raise in deletes to shake downvotes and regular "do that homework for me" posts (one common way is to split an assignment into essentially one line per question).

Even if one spends 1-2 hours per question (good starting point for ["a lot of research"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)) 6 questions already take most of the day to prepare.

Notes

- so far "6 recent questions" that got you to the throttle limit stand at -2/+1 total score. I don't think that would be considered "they're positively received" even if suggestion is implemented (don't forget that 0 is *not* a positive score from SO point of view at least when evaluated for the question ban).
- asking ["Parse JSON with undefined value?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59305534/parse-json-with-undefined-value) when you should have known from your research that such *text* is not *JSON* is almost as bad as asking why particular undefined behavior leads to given result in C/C++ tags... Not *showing* research in the post (5-10 minutes needed to read JSON specification  is hardly "a lot" but at least some) is explicitly specified reason for downvotes. Spending some more time on writing the question to demonstrate your research (i.e. by not claiming "parse JSON") would make question much better (again eating some of that time of the day that leads to throttle :) )